# Print Elements of Array in Select Attribute

Tags: angularjs

I am having an array of quantities [250 Gram,  500 Gram,  1KG,  2 pieces,  4 pieces] coming from server side. I want to display this array in jsp in select attribute. How can I do this using angularjs ?

The elements inside array may vary depending on the values coming from server side.

Well this is my complete array that am getting from serverside:

[{"price":40,"name":"Apple","primaryKey":21701,"quantity":"[250 Gram,  500 Gram,  1KG,  2 pieces,  4 pieces]"},{"price":0,"name":"Banana","primaryKey":21705,"quantity":"[250 Gram,  500 Gram,  1KG]"},{"price":0,"name":"Pomegranate","primaryKey":21709,"quantity":"[250 Gram,  500 Gram]"},{"price":0,"name":"Orange","primaryKey":21713,"quantity":"[250 Gram,  500 Gram,  1KG,  2KG]"}]

Now, what I want is to display the quantity part in select attribute.

Comment: What have you researched/attempted so far? Please post some code.

Comment: @TimOgilvy Well I have used ng-repeat for displaying them.

Comment: You should prefer using ngOptions. Read the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select. But anyway, what was the problem with your attempt of using ng-repeat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you want something like this?

**Edited:** Please keep in mind that this is more of a hack than a real solution. A real solution would be to get the proper value from server side. If you don't have access to the server side then this should do just fine.

```js
var app = angular.module('theApp', []);
app.controller('myctrlR', function($scope) {
  $scope.SelectedItem = [];
  $scope.items = [{
    "price": 40,
    "name": "Apple",
    "primaryKey": 21701,
    "quantity": "[250 Gram, 500 Gram, 1KG, 2 pieces, 4 pieces]"
  }, {
    "price": 0,
    "name": "Banana",
    "primaryKey": 21705,
    "quantity": "[250 Gram, 500 Gram, 1KG]"
  }, {
    "price": 0,
    "name": "Pomegranate",
    "primaryKey": 21709,
    "quantity": "[250 Gram, 500 Gram]"
  }, {
    "price": 0,
    "name": "Orange",
    "primaryKey": 21713,
    "quantity": "[250 Gram, 500 Gram, 1KG, 2KG]"
  }]

  angular.forEach($scope.items, function(val, key) {
    val.quantity = val.quantity.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').split(', ')
  })
})
```

```html
<html ng-app="theApp">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js">
</script>
<div ng-controller="myctrlR">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items" style="margin-bottom:20px;" ng-init="SelectedItem[$index]=''">
    <div>{{item.name}} - Price: ${{item.price}}</div>
    <select ng-model="SelectedItem[$index]" ng-options="x for x in item.quantity track by x">
      <option value="">Select Item</option>
    </select>
    <div>Selected Item is: <strong>{{SelectedItem[$index]}}</strong>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Exactly. I tried the same. But only problem is my array which is coming from server side is:   $scope.items = [250 Gram, 500 Gram, 1KG, 2 pieces, 4 pieces]. I hope you noticed the difference. This is where it is creating issue.