# AngularJS filter array with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS search filter, with a search box.
I'd like to add in checkbox filtering, via a function or pure AngularJS.
The checkboxes should filter the array called cat(short for category).

**My data sits in an array called cat( short for category).
A product can have multiple categories, for example:**

```
product_A.cat: [ 'Continuing Education', 'Scientific Session']
```

**My junior developer tried creating a filter function for each checkbox.
But I want to move a way from that.**

```
<h4 class="blue-title">Filter by category:</h4>
                    <div class="navbar">

                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button class="navbar-toggle btn btn-block" id="filtercategories"
                                type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                                data-target=".searchbar-collapse">
                                <span class="fa fa-filter"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Categories
                            </button>
                        </div>

                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse searchbar-collapse">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block"
                                style="margin: 7px 0;" ng-click="resetFilters()">RESET
                                FILTERS</button>
                        </div>

                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse searchbar-collapse">
                            <h5 style="font-weight: bold;">FREE</h5>
                            <div ng-repeat="FREEcategory in FREE">
                                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="FREEcategory.on"
                                    ng-change="FREEcheckChange()"> {{FREEcategory.name}}
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse searchbar-collapse">
                            <h5 style="font-weight: bold;">CONTINUING EDUCATION</h5>
                            <div ng-repeat="CEcategory in CE">
                                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="CEcategory.on"> {{CEcategory.name}}
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse searchbar-collapse">
                            <h5 style="font-weight: bold;">BEST OF ATS CONFERENCE</h5>
                            <div ng-repeat="BATScategory in BATS">
                                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="BATScategory.on"
                                    ng-change="BATScheckChange()"> {{BATScategory.name}}
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse searchbar-collapse">
                            <h5 style="font-weight: bold;">APCCMPD</h5>
                            <div ng-repeat="APCCMPDcategory in APCCMPD">
                                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="APCCMPDcategory.on"
                                    ng-change="APCCMPDcheckChange()">
                                {{APCCMPDcategory.name}}
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse searchbar-collapse">
                            <h5 style="font-weight: bold;">YEAR</h5>
                            <div ng-repeat="YEARcategory in YEAR">
                                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="YEARcategory.on"
                                    ng-change="YEARcheckChange()"> {{YEARcategory.name}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Check for my answer in this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36372797/2825245 - In this example I am using select box. You can easily change it to Checkboxes.

Comment: I dont think your use case applies.